# How do I loop through an array then filter it based on the output of .some()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, filter

I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to use filter within a loop.

```
const roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]];
const cityWithMostRoads = 1;
let filteredCityList = [["0", 2],["3", 2]];
```

I believe there is an issue with line 5. When `filter` takes place, the element in `[0]` is removed, the second element that was at `[1]` now becomes `[0]`. Essentially, after the `filter` method is ran, `filteredCityList[1][0]` no longer exists for the loop to run as intended.

```
1   if(filteredCityList.length > 0) {      
2      for(let i = 0; i < filteredCityList.length; i++) {
3      let pair = ([a, b]) => a == filteredCityList[i][0] && b == cityWithMostRoads || a == cityWithMostRoads && b == filteredCityList[i][0];
4        if(roads.some(pair)) {
5          filteredCityList = filteredCityList.filter(x => x[0] !== filteredCityList[i][0])
6        };
7      };
8   };
9 
10  console.log(filteredCityList);
```

**Desired output:**

```
filteredCityList = []
```

**Current output:**

```
filteredCityList = [["3", 2]]
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Would help if you provided an explanation of the filter criteria. Your code is far more complex than needed and is hard to tell exactly what should or shouldn't match

Comment: @charlietfl - If `[1, 0]` or `[0, 1]` is found in array `roads`, then filter `0` from `filteredCityList`. Also, if `[1, 3] or [3, 1] ` is found in array `roads`, then filter `3` from `filteredCityList`. I am using a for loop because `filteredCityList` can include more items than it is currently listed in the array.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an element whose index is less than or equal to current loop's `i`, then you will possibly skip some elements in subsequent loops, one way around this problem is to use `splice` to remove elements and correct the `i` at the same time:

```js
const roads = [[0,1],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3]];
const cityWithMostRoads = 1;
let filteredCityList = [["0", 2],["3", 2]];

 if(filteredCityList.length > 0) {      
     for(let i = 0; i < filteredCityList.length; i++) {

     let pair = ([a, b]) => a == filteredCityList[i][0] && b == cityWithMostRoads || a == cityWithMostRoads && b == filteredCityList[i][0];
       if(roads.some(pair)) {
         let target = filteredCityList[i][0];
         //loops backwards to remove elements 
         for(let j = filteredCityList.length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            if(filteredCityList[j][0] === target){
               filteredCityList.splice(j, 1);
               if(j <= i) i--; // correct `i`
            }
         }
 
       };
     };
  };
 
console.log(filteredCityList);
```